# I want to get canvas into my pdf.but not finding the way to do so.actual output is different from the expected one

Tags: javascript, html

i used  'pdfmake' to generate and download pdf.getting all the other parameters but unable to get the canvas which i am showing as a result in the form of pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your page to an image first since `pdfmake` doesn't allow some parts of svg to print into the PDF.

use `html2canvas` for html to image conversion and then.

```
 const ref = document.getElementById('print');

 html2canvas(ref, {
            allowTaint: true
        }).then(function (canvas) {
            const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            const docDefinition = {
                pageSize: { width: 600, height: ref.clientHeight },
                content: [
                    {
                        image: dataURL,
                        fit: [ref.clientHeight, (ref.clientHeight - 200)],
                    }
                ]
            };
            pdfmake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('fileName.pdf');
            hidePrintPreviewModal();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
```